# Random row in Scala Slick 3.0

Tags: scala, slick

How do I get one random row out of a table efficiently?

What I have so far (doesn't compile and probably completely misguided):

```
val query = for {
  m <- tableQuery
  maxId <- tableQuery.groupBy(_.id).map { case (tId, t) => t.map(_.id).max}//m.map(_.id).max
  if (m.id >= maxId * Random.nextFloat())
} yield m
```

**Edit:** after some tinkering and with the help of bhavya i've come up with the following code which does the job but makes two database roundtrips:

```
val maxIdQuery: Rep[Option[Int]] = magicCardDumps.map(_.id).max
val maxIdFuture: Future[Option[Int]] = db.run(maxIdQuery.result)
val maxId = Await.result(maxIdFuture, 10 seconds).get
val randCardQuery: Query[MagicCardDumps, MagicCardDump, Seq] = magicCardDumps.filter(_.id >= (maxId * Random.nextFloat()).toInt).sortBy(_.id).take(1)
val resultFuture: Future[Seq[MagicCardDump]] = db.run(randCardQuery.result)
val resultSeq: Seq[MagicCardDump]= Await.result(resultFuture, Duration(10, "seconds"))
val card = resultSeq.head
println(card)
```

How can these queries be merged into one and made more efficient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to do it is to use `SimpleFuction`

```
val rand = SimpleFunction.nullary[Double]("rand")
query.sortBy(x => rand).take(1)
```

Works in Postgres and MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps :

```
val rowElementAsOpt = for {
  maxId <- Query(tableQuery.map(_.id).max).first
  result <- tableQuery.filter(_.id >= maxId*Random.nextFloat).firstOption // fetches the first element of the resultset as an Option 
} yield result

rowElementAsOpt match{
case Some(rowElement) => // A random row  
case None => // No row
```

Comment: the functions first and firstOption do not exist, if i replace them with take(1) I get an error on the multiplication:
`Cannot perform option-mapped operation
with type: (Option[Int], Float) => R
for base type: (Int, Int) => Int`

Comment: This piece of code was tested for slick 2.10 not 3.0 . May be the  3.0 version has some different syntax .